# conda error: zstandard could not be imported

Tags: python, conda

My Conda (on Ubuntu 18.04) has the following error message but all functions are running correctly:

```
/home/td7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_package_streaming/package_streaming.py:19: UserWarning: zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.
  warnings.warn("zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.")
/home/td7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_package_handling/api.py:29: UserWarning: Install zstandard Python bindings for .conda support
  _warnings.warn("Install zstandard Python bindings for .conda support")
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): | /home/td7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_package_streaming/package_streaming.py:19: UserWarning: zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.
  warnings.warn("zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.")
/home/td7920/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda_package_handling/api.py:29: UserWarning: Install zstandard Python bindings for .conda support
  _warnings.warn("Install zstandard Python bindings for .conda support")
```

I did pip install zstandard and conda install zstandard. When I do conda list, both are found,

```
zstandard                 0.19.0           py38h5945529_1    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.5.1                  pypi_0    pypi
```

But still get the error.

Comment: Only see warnings (please don't call warnings errors). Try updating `conda` and `conda-package-handling` packages. Also, you're only complicating things by bringing in PyPI. Users simply should not be install PyPI packages in **base**. Reinstall `zstd` from Conda Forge.

Comment: Updating the base python to newest (in my case from 3.9 to 3.11) and then updating conda solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 19):

What worked for me:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall zstandard
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall zstd
```

Received new version `zstd` from `pip ... --force-reinstall` that I did not from `conda ... --force-reinstall`.  Have channels:

- bioconda
- r
- anaconda
- conda-forge
- defaults

in .condarc ?  Yes!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note that some more info about why the pip (0.21) version works but the conda-forge version (0.19) did not can be found here: https://github.com/conda/conda-libmamba-solver/issues/241

Comment: What is interesting is that this is a catch-22 situation: in order to be able to install zstandard 0.21 you first need to update zstandard! Fortunately there is a workaround by first updating zstandard via pip, and then you will see that `conda search zstandard` will show 0.21 as latest instead of 0.19

Comment: More explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77340146/4126843

Answer (score 2):

I am on a Windows 11 box and have exclusively used Anaconda / conda / navigator to install and update packages, avoiding at all costs using pip.
Using:
Python 3.10.9 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Mar  1 2023, 18:18:15) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

I too ran into this problem and tried most of the posted answers, to no avail. I tried importing zstandard in a plain conda env python window and it prompted me about conflicts between compiled versions. So I guessed a simple force installation via pip of the newest version of zstandard was a risk worth taking.

I went to https://pypi.org/project/zstandard/ got the most recent version number, at the time of this writing was 0.21.0, and within a conda env terminal window ran pip install zstandard==0.21.0 and the problem has disappeared.

For each of my environments I have done the same and have no more issues.

Comment: To simplify David's answer above, downgrading to this specific version helped me magically:
`pip install zstandard==0.21.0`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to fix this issue. We need to `import zstandard` in the following two *.py* files and everything will be smooth as wind.

> /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_package_handling/api.py

> /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda_package_streaming/package_streaming.py